# ASP.NET Consuming Webservices and reading the Soap Message

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I am having difficulties Understanding and consuming Webservices in asp.net .
i've created some Webmethods to be exposed , and tested them using the (Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/") and then i created a simple client application , that calls one of the functions through passing it as the "action" parameter in the form tag , something like :

```
<form id="form1"  action='http://localhost:3880/SoapService/Service.asmx/HelloWorld'
method="post">
```

What i can't figured out:

- if possible a better Explination of Webservices and how they use and consume SOAP Messages
- How to pass Parameters with the function call, when i put the function url in the action parameter , like above.
- How to consume the soap message itself. (is that possible?)

Comment: This article should help explain things a little. [Tutorial on Creating ASP.NET Web Service](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/aspwebsvr.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

maybe this will help to reads incoming request parameters for Web services

[UrlParameterReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.urlparameterreader.aspx)

- and i think the following will answer ur third question
  [Click here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480498.aspx)

Comment: +1, thanks for the articles, looks pretty helpful,will come back when i am done reading :)